# How do I multiply grouped values inside a column of data.table and return the data.table only with the result rows

Tags: r, data.table

How do I multiply the values inside a column by grouping from another column.
Let's say I have :

```
dt = data.table(group = c(1,1,2,2), value = c(2,3,4,5))
```

I want to multiply the elements of the value with each other but only the ones that belong to the same group , hence that would return.

```
dt=data.table(group=c(1,2), value=c(6,20))
```

I tried it with cumprod

```
dt[, new_value := cumprod(value), by = group]
```

but then that returns
`dt=data.table(group=c(1,1,2,2), value=c(2,6,4,20))` and I don't know how to remove the rows that i dont neeed: those with value(2,4)
...
Taking the maximum is not a solution because the values could also be negative.

Comment: i think just `prod` would suffice: `dt[, prod(value), group]`

Answer (score 2):

Updating for visibility using @chinsoon12 solution in the comments.

```
dt[, .(new_value = prod(value)), by = group]
```

---

Here's one option where you first perform the calculation and then take the last row by group.

```
dt[, .(new_value = cumprod(value)), by = group][,.SD[.N], by = group]
```

```
   group new_value
1:     1         6
2:     2        20
```

Comment: For code-golf, brevity, and declarative code, I suggest using chinsoon12's recommendation replacing `cumprod` with `prod`, removing the need for your second `[`-expression completely.